# How to build each Project separately

Tags: c#, f#-fake

I have several Test-Projects which contains a file with the same name: "loc.xml".
If I build all Test-Projects so my "loc.xml" will be overwritten every time.

Is there a way to build each project in a separate folder?

Actually i use this:

```
Target "BuildUnitTests" (fun _ ->
   trace "Building unit tests..."
   !! @"source\test\**\*.csproj"
     |> MSBuildRelease BuildParams.TestsOutputDir "Rebuild"
     |> Log "AppBuild-Output: "
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by iterating over each project in your glob from `!! @"source\test\**\*.csproj"` and specifying a build directory as an option to MSBuild.

Here's a very basic `build.fsx` file that does the following:

- Glob all files of pattern `source/test/**/*.csproj`
- Iterate over glob and send it to a function that parses out filename of the unit test
- Set the build directory to `bin/PROJECT_NAME`
- Send project file to `MSBuild` function, with parameters to make it build in `Release` mode, an option for output directory.

After you run it, you should have a bunch of subfolders in `bin` that are named liked your unit test project names, and the artifacts of each respective build should be in the correct folder.

---

```
#I "packages/FAKE/tools"
#r "FakeLib.dll"

open System.IO
open Fake

let buildProject (projectName : string) =
    // Just setting a release configuration by default...
    let properties = [ ("Configuration", "Release") ]

    let bareName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(projectName)
    let buildDir = sprintf "bin/%s" bareName
    trace <| sprintf "Building %s" bareName

    // MSBuildHelper's functions all expect a list so you have to pass
    // projectName as part of a list.
    // We are using 'naked' MSBuild so we have to specify all the
    // options/arguments ourselves
    MSBuild buildDir "Rebuild" properties [projectName]
    |> ignore

Target "Build" <| fun () ->
    !! "source/test/**/*.csproj" 
    |> Seq.iter buildProject

Target "All" DoNothing
"Build" ==> "All"

RunTargetOrDefault "All"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, than different projects should be built into different folders automatically.

However, you may change the build path for each project in properties (project properties -> build -> output path).

Comment: Yes, this is the natural operating mode of VS. But i build here with F# Make as you can see on the Tags.

Comment: @DannySotzny F# Projects behave just like C#. 
So, if you add new project to solution - simply choose new folder for it.

Comment: sure, i could build every Project separately. But then i must set every Projectname in script. I´m looking for a solution which works generally.
My Idea is to fetch the list of csproj-Files and to iterate them - but i don´t know how.